# Etymology of "shagged [out]" (BrE exhausted, knackered)

Tags: etymology, british-english, slang

I was intrigued by [this comment to an earlier ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111326/why-is-the-noun-sex-uncountable#comment226076_111330)...

> [**shagged out**] Meaning 'very tired', presumably originating from having lots of sex but used generally to mean tired for whatever reason

...which led me to [this dictionary.com entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shagged+out)...

> **shagged**  [shagd] adjective Informal
>   weary; exhausted (usually followed by out)
>    *They were completely shagged out from the long trip.*
>   Origin: 1930–35;  origin uncertain

OED tells me the coarse BrE slang verb *to shag* is also "origin uncertain" (perhaps relating to a rare/obsolete verb sense *shag=toss about*).

Does anyone know anything more about this? Was that ELU commenter on the right track?

---

EDIT: Just to clarify. Effectively, I'm asking two questions:

> 1: Are *shagged=tired* and *shag=fuck* [cognate?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cognate) (do they have a common origin?)
>    2: If so, does that mean the commenter was right (i.e. - *shagged=tired* originally implied *post-coital*)?

Comment: [folk etymology #1] "Man, I was so tired I passed out on the soft, comfy *shag carpet*" ;)

Comment: [folk etymology #2] "I was dancing *The Shag* all night long. I'm exhausted!"

Comment: Shog off mate ! (perhaps)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, I thought you were looking for a possible source of _shag_ for _sex_. _Shagged out_ has always meant _knackered_ to me, _knackered_ has always meant _worn out_ in the sense of old horses combined with the testicles (being worn out).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - just to know, did I misunderstand you question? Are you asking about the sex allusion origin in 'shagged out' or something else?

Comment: @Josh61: Will edit to clarify. My first thought was to suppose *shagged out=tired* and *shag=fuck* must be "cognates" (same etymology", because I class them both as *coarse slang*. But I backpedalled when I realised I also class both *knackered=tired* and *knackers=testicles* as equally coarse slang, but I know perfectly well those two senses are *not* cognate.

Comment: [Not entirely unrelated](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/142947), Shaggy.

Answer (score 1):

The copulation sense of shag certainly seems to have come first, so to speak. From Francis Grose, *A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*, Third Edition (1796):

> TO SHAG. To copulate. He is but bad shag; he is no able woman's man.

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, Fifth Edition (1961) sees the same possible connection that you do:

> shag, v.t. To coit (with a woman) : late C. 18–20. Very gen. among soldiers in G.W. Grose, 2nd ed. Prob. ex [obsolete] *shag*, to shake,toss about. ...2. Whence, perhaps, v.i., to masturbate : Public Schools : certainly ca. 1900 and prob. many years earlier.
>
> shag, adj. Exhausted, esp. after games : Marlborough College : C. 20. Perhaps ex *shag*, v., 2, q.v. (A thin and weedy dog that, ca. 1919–23, haunted the college precincts, was known as *Shagpak* or *Shaghat*, as Mr. A.B.R. Fairclough, formerly of the Alcuin Press, tells me.)

Interestingly, Partridge also has an entry for "wet as a shag" (from circa 1830), meaning "very wet indeed," in reference to the cormorant (or shag), whose feathers lack the oil that many swimming birds possess and thus get very wet indeed. This also explains the cormorant's habit of standing on a dock, rock, or tree branch with its wings motionlessly outstretched, to dry its feathers. I'm a bit surprised that Partridge didn't entertain the possibility that the exhausted sense of *shagged* might derive from the bird's motionless torpor at such times, following a vigorous session of fish catching.

John Ayto & John Simpson, *The Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang* (1992) takes a view *shag* and *shagged* that is similar to Partridge's:

> **shag (1)** *coarse. verb trans and intr.* **1** To have sex (with) 1788– ... **2** Used in curses and exclamations 1933– ... **3** An act of copulation. 1937– **4** One who copulates; used as a general term of abuse. 1971– ... [Origin uncertain; perh. from obs. *shag* to shake, waggle.]
>
> ...
>
> **shagged** *adjective* Weary, exhausted; often followed by *out*. 1932– ...{Origin uncertain; perh. related to SHAG (1) verb.]

Ayto & Simpson also notes the existence of a verb *shag* from 1851 meaning "to wander aimlessly; to traipse; to go away." That term's origin is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

When I was at school in the 1960s and forced to go on cross-country runs, my PE teacher used to insist we used a running style called *shagging*.

This caused a certain amount of schoolboy amusement due to the other use of the word.  Shagging was a running style which used less energy over a long run.  It would be known to most people as jogging.  This would explain exhaustion.

I have never heard shagging used this way by anyone else.  It may be a dialect word.  The teacher in question was from South Wales but the Welsh language can't be blamed for this use of shagging.

Comment: That seems slightly worrisome ... when I was at school we had a deep mistrust of all PE teachers.

Comment: I wonder if there's a link with this etymology of [jog](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jog&allowed_in_frame=): '1540s, "to shake up and down," perhaps altered from Middle English shoggen "to shake, jolt, move with a jerk" (late 14c.), of uncertain origin. Meanings "shake," "stir up by hint or push," and "walk or ride with a jolting pace" are from 16c.' "Jogging" in a S Wales accent could sound a little like "shogging".

Comment: Here's a shagging/run possibility https://archive.org/stream/areporttrialrev00courgoog#page/n36/mode/2up page 28. Issac Burdick.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the verb to shag has both origin ' copulate' and current slang meaning related to sex;

[Shag](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Shag&searchmode=none): etymology

> - "copulate with," 1788, probably from obsolete verb shag (late 14c.) "to shake, waggle," which probably is connected to shake (v.).

[Shag](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shag):

> - v. shagged, shag·ging, shags Chiefly British Vulgar Slang.
> - v.tr.
>   To engage in sexual intercourse with.
>   v.intr.
>   To engage in sexual intercourse.
>   [Perhaps from obsolete shag, to shake, wiggle.]

Comment: Looks like you’ve forgotten to attribute in plaintext here.